# ATS and Ad Hoc distribution

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Do I Need to enable/keep ATS when I am distributing my application using "ad-hoc" provision profile (no store)?

Comment: Any urls you use you can place in the exception domains key in the Info.plist file and you should be fine.

Comment: Have you tried running an app ad-hoc with the allows arbitrary loads flag on?

Comment: Simple_code, thank you very much! You are right.